# Light switch timer for outside lights

Tags: lighting, switch, timer

We just moved into a house that has outside patio lights controlled by 3 different light switches.  I want to replace one of the light switches with a digital timer. What type of light switch timer do I need?  3 pole?  4 pole?  And does it matter which light switch I decide to replace in the circuit?

Comment: All the lights are controlled by 3 switches, or there are 3 switches that each control some of the lights?

Answer (score 2):

It matters which one you replace, because that will determine which type of timer you need. One of those switches is going to be the "middle" switch, between the other two circuit-wise. That middle switch is a four-way switch, the two outside switches are three-way switches. You can determine which is which visually is you don't know the circuit layout - the three-ways will have three wires plus a ground, the four-way will have four wires plus a ground attached to each switch.

This is a simplified and idealized example of the circuit you're dealing with:

[image: simplified 4-way switch circuit wiring]

Comment: Great explanation and diagram, John. So... all I would need to do is  to find which switch is the 3 way, and then use a 3 way switch timer?

Comment: There will be two three-way switches as shown here. Find either one of them, and if you can find a three-way switch timer - I've neither seen nor heard of such a beastie - replace the one you've found.

Comment: What about this switch?http://www.amazon.com/Honeywell-Sunrise-PLS750C1000-required-Ti072-3w/dp/B004ZFNL16/ref=cm_wl_huc_item#Ask

Comment: According to the manual, that switch should work - if you follow the installation instructions carefully and it works as documented. Of course, with the 4-way switch in there, you may need to talk to Honeywell support...

Comment: +1 for the Honeywell link.  We installed those for the front porch.  Set your lat+long and it will come on at dusk and turn off at dawn.  Matched to some efficient LED bulbs and they work great.

Comment: Update: John, unfortunately that switch didn't work.  Both my 3 way switches do not have White Neutral wires in the receptacles which are needed per the manual. Damn it! Back to searching for solutions....

Comment: If you don't have white wires in the device box, you have bigger problems and I strongly recommend you contract an electrician to go any further.

Comment: John, finally found a work around to my problem. First, deactivated 4 way switch (black-black, red-red). Then circuit becomes a simple 3 way circuit. Second, found a 3-way switch timer that doesn't require white neutral. Intermatic EJ500. All wired.  Seems to be working fine for the past couple of weeks. Again, thanks for all your help.